# Merge 2nd column for each 1st column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, merge

I have data that looks like

```
ABC     1234,2134,6754,7658
XYZ     4324,5643,6754,9832,5478,0987
DEF     2938,4637,1093,6734,5632
GHI     3274
ABC     9983
DEF     1211,4782
```

What I want is to merge the 2nd column for each ID in 1st column

```
ABC     1234,2134,6754,7658,9983 
XYZ     4324,5643,6754,9832,5478,0987
DEF     2938,4637,1093,6734,5632,1211,4782
GHI     3274
```

What I was thinking is programmatically iterate over each ID in 1st column (sorted). Continue for each ID until it doesn't match the next row. Can this be done with a SQL query instead. How can I go about it?. I have about 100k rows. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how well it would perform, but MySQL has [an aggregate function called `GROUP_CONCAT` that concatenates its arguments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Assuming your fully-assembled columns won't exceed 1024 characters, you can do something like:

```
SELECT first_column,
       GROUP_CONCAT(second_column ORDER BY ... SEPARATOR ',')
  FROM table_name
 GROUP
    BY first_column
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that.

Example:

If table you provided as example is named `table1` with columns `col1` and `col2` then the query to achieve required result will look like this:

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2 SEPARATOR ',') FROM table1 GROUP BY col1;
```